# Do helicopters use Ground speed or True airspeed?

Tags: aircraft-design, instrument-flight-rules, visual-flight-rules

Is there a limit on the speed and minimum altitude of the helicopter before switching between the two?

Comment: This question is a little bit unclear.  Are you asking if helicopters used true airspeed or ground speed?

Comment: Why do you think helicopters would be different from other aircraft?

Comment: I can't even tell how the text lines up with the title question.

Comment: Could this question have to do with hovering?  If you are landing and taking off with wind present then your transition to weight on wheels will take place at zero ground speed. In the hover you are also maintaining zero ground speed.  Once in forward flight indicated airspeed is used for normal flying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helicopters, like any other aircraft, can make use of true airspeed read outs as well as groundspeed readouts.  There are no altitude or speed limits for using the two. Helicopters do, depending on the air frame, have a limits as to a maximum forward air speed due to retreating blade stall problems.  This limit would be in calibrated airspeed, as opposed to a true airspeed or ground speed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define the term “use”, but most aircraft, helicopters included, use indicated airspeed, most of the time.

Indicated airspeed is used because the airspeed indicator indicates indicated airspeed.  And the airspeed indicator is a primary flight instrument.

TAS and GS are useful references in flight planning and navigation, but they aren’t used to fly the airplane.  Most small GA aircraft don’t display TAS, and GS would only be displayed on a GPS navigation screen.  Any “switching” between them would not be a function of airspeed, but instead a function of your purpose and need.

For example, if you want to run a quick time/distance calculation to a point you would use ground speed.  (Actually if you have ground speed displayed in flight your system probably gives you time to go). TAS is mostly useful for determining zero wind ground speed in preflight navigation planning.

I am less familiar with helicopters, but I would surmise that options to use either TAS or GS as a reference would be similarly driven more by their instrumentation package than the means of producing lift.

It’s important to understand the distinctions, but inflight your life depends on indicated airspeed.  That’s what the dial or EFIS tape shows, and that’s what pilots fly by 99% of the time.